# Computing Gauss's Law for Plasma Oscillation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, plasma-physics

For deriving the equation for plasma frequency, we first compute the electric field using Gauss's Law and then use that in the equation of motion.

[image: Source: Inan and Golkowski]

Image source: *Principles of Plasma Physics*, Inan and Golkowski

Here, we have two slabs: a stationary ion slab and a movable electron slab. If we moved the electron slab, say, to the right, we induce an electric field as shown in the image.

$\oint_{S} \vec{E}.d\vec{s} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$, where $Q$ is the total charge contained within closed surface $S$.

$Q = A x N_e q_e$, where $N_e$ is the number density of electrons.

Assuming that $a$ is the dimension of the rectangular-box surface in the $y$ direction and that the depth of the box is $\Delta z$, we have

$\oint_{S} \vec{E}.d\vec{s} = -a \Delta z E_x = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0} = \frac{a x \Delta z N_e q_e}{\epsilon_0}$

This gives, $E_x = -\frac{x N_e q_e}{\epsilon_0}$

And then we move on to the equation of motion part to derive the frequency (no issues there).

My question is, where did the negative come from?

In *Introduction to Plasma Physics* by Gurnett and Bhattacharjee, we have a similar derivation, with some changes in the notations used. So, it is safe to assume that it was not a misprint.

I'm sure I'm missing or overlooking something trivial, but, I'm unable to figure out what that is. Help me understand what I'm missing.

TIA!

Comment: I think it's because the electric field is in the opposite direction to the outwards-pointing normal of $S$, giving rise to the negative sign.

Comment: @ZadeJohnston, as I understand, the restoring force hasn't acted yet at the time of calculating the electric field. So, the directions of the displacement and the electric field are both in the positive-x direction.

Comment: The integral $\oint \vec E \cdot \vec{ds}$ here is a surface integral over the surface $S$ (Gauss's law), rather than a line integral used for calculating work. $\vec E$ is non-zero only on the left-hand side of the surface, which has an outwards normal vector $\vec{ds}$ pointing left, and so $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{ds} < 0$.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is helpful or not: I believe this kind of derivation is also in Feynman lectures. Did you consider going through it?